# How to arrange a daily time series of columns into rows and columns?

Tags: r

Data looks like this:

```
Date    Precipitation
1/1/1979    0
1/2/1979    0
1/3/1979    0.024032592
1/4/1979    0.185394276
1/5/1979    0
1/6/1979    0
1/7/1979    0
1/8/1979    0.47378538
1/9/1979    2.63843586
1/10/1979   1.522637316
1/11/1979   0.161361698
1/12/1979   0.366497035
1/13/1979   0.05493163
1/14/1979   0.659179584
1/15/1979   1.53293652
1/16/1979   1.50032075
1/17/1979   0.137329142
1/18/1979   0.181961042
1/19/1979   0
1/20/1979   0
1/21/1979   0.955295748
1/22/1979   1.096916321
1/23/1979   1.203346346
1/24/1979   5.04255528
1/25/1979   4.711243248
1/26/1979   0.044631972
1/27/1979   0.82225769
1/28/1979   3.266720129
1/29/1979   2.849578344
1/30/1979   0.885772253
1/31/1979   0.003433226
```

and i want it to look as such,

```
Year    Month   1   2   3 . . . .
1979    1   0   0   0.024032592 . . .
```

I am doing SPI analysis.

Comment: What have you tried yet!! it seems like a homework question

Comment: I am doing assignment on Drought analysis using SPI if you know it and just needed to cut time. I am new in R.

Comment: try `tidyr::pivot_wider()` or search existing questions here.  Even you have not included the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the 6 row data frame DF0 shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, add a day column, read it as zoo object splitting by day using yearmon index class (year and month without day).  Then create a data frame with year and  month and the other columns.

```
library(magrittr)
library(zoo)

fmt <- "%m/%d/%Y"
DF0 %>%
  transform(day = as.POSIXlt(Date, format = fmt)$mday) %>%
  read.zoo(FUN = as.yearmon, format = fmt, split = "day") %>%
  data.frame(year = as.integer(time(.)), month = cycle(time(.)), ., 
    check.names = FALSE)
```

giving this data frame:

```
         year month 1 2          3         4 5 6
Jan 1979 1979     1 0 0 0.02403259 0.1853943 0 0
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
Date    Precipitation
1/1/1979    0
1/2/1979    0
1/3/1979    0.024032592
1/4/1979    0.185394276
1/5/1979    0
1/6/1979    0
1/7/1979    0
1/8/1979    0.47378538
1/9/1979    2.63843586
1/10/1979   1.522637316
1/11/1979   0.161361698
1/12/1979   0.366497035
1/13/1979   0.05493163
1/14/1979   0.659179584
1/15/1979   1.53293652
1/16/1979   1.50032075
1/17/1979   0.137329142
1/18/1979   0.181961042
1/19/1979   0
1/20/1979   0
1/21/1979   0.955295748
1/22/1979   1.096916321
1/23/1979   1.203346346
1/24/1979   5.04255528
1/25/1979   4.711243248
1/26/1979   0.044631972
1/27/1979   0.82225769
1/28/1979   3.266720129
1/29/1979   2.849578344
1/30/1979   0.885772253
1/31/1979   0.003433226"
DF0 <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, nrow = 6)
```

Comment: G. Grothendieck - it worked like a charm. Thanks.